# VM Azure PowerShell: Get principals/users to which a virtual machine was assigned to

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, amazon-iam

I want to get the list of users/principals to which a virtual machine was assigned to using an Azure RM PowerShell cmdlet or an API.

Comment: could you define: "users to which a virtual machine was assigned"? how do you assign a vm to a user?

Comment: I want to get the list of role assignments to a given virtual machine : (VM - Access Control (IAM))

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK your ask can be accomplished by [Azure Az PowerShell Get-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-1.7.0) / [AzureRM PowerShell Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermroleassignment?view=azurermps-6.13.0) / [Azure REST API Get Role Assignments For Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/listforresource)

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!